# Mac App: Pdf Compiler to generate “reports”

Tags: software-development, osx, pdf, merge

I'm looking for a mac compatible software that can take multiple PDF-files as input, and output a merged and structured compilation of those files into one single PDF. The purpose being: making a congruent "report" from multiple files.

What it as to be able to do for me:

Merge multiple files into one
Insert page number on every page
Generate a table of contents from the file names of the uploaded files
Insert a predesigned front page on page 1 of every compilation
If possible, it would also be great if it could structure the layout of each files so it looks like a a uniform report, and not just a compilations of random files.

Does anyone know of any software or web-based app/software that has these functionalities? Or perhaps any ideas of where to look? I've googled this for days but not found a suitable solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

## PDF Toolkit

The [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can do a lot of what you are asking for, there is a free edition, ($0.00), and a pro-edition, (for a very reasonable $3.99), - both with windows GUIs and both include the cross platform command line server edition.

PDFTK Free GUI
[image: GUI]

PDFtk Server can:

- Merge PDF Documents or Collate PDF Page Scans
- Split PDF Pages into a New Document
- Rotate PDF Documents or Pages
- Decrypt Input as Necessary (Password Required)
- Encrypt Output as Desired
- Fill PDF Forms with X/FDF Data and/or Flatten Forms
- Generate FDF Data Stencils from PDF Forms
- Apply a Background Watermark or a Foreground Stamp
- Report PDF Metrics, Bookmarks and Metadata
- Add/Update PDF Bookmarks or Metadata
- Attach Files to PDF Pages or the PDF Document
- Unpack PDF Attachments
- Burst a PDF Document into Single Pages
- Uncompress and Re-Compress Page Streams
- Repair Corrupted PDF (Where Possible)

PDFtk Server does not require Adobe Acrobat or Reader, and it runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

The TOC could be produced by creating a separate PDF Document that contains the details and merging that in but AFAIK the consistent style would not be possible with this tool.

## ReportLab

There is also the combination of [Python](http://python.org), [PDFMiner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) and [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/) which could, with quite a bit more work setting things up, Merge, Generate TOC and reformat to a consistent style providing the original pdfs have been generated in a manner that allows this, *i.e. not from a scanner and not from some programs that draw the text into the document in a complex manner.*

Python and PDFMiner are free & Open Source.
ReportLab offers Free & Open Source (£0.00), paid for ReportLab PLUS, (pricing depending on pages/month generated and start at £1200 per annum *doubled for the financial services industry*), or bespoke solutions which unless their rates are really high ***may*** cost less to implement than roll your own if you include your development hours.